# unwanted character output with putchar

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that asks a user to input a character for an answer to a test, and I used `putchar(toupper(questionAnswer))` to make sure the answer the user gave was always uppercase (to make comparing the user answers to the test key easier), but whenever I use `putchar()` it outputs the capitalized user output even though there is no `cout` that does that.

I have looked for other problems relating to `putchar()`, but I haven't been able to find any problems similar to mine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  const string CLEAR = "\033[2J\033[1;1H";
  string testAnswers;
  int status, newKey;
  char newAnswer, choice, keyChoice, endProgram, questionAnswer, answers[20] = {'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A'};
  do{
    //starting prompt
    cout << CLEAR;
    cout << "Teacher or Student:\n1.Teacher\n2.Student\n";
    cin >> status;
    while(status > 2 || status < 1){
      cout << "Enter valid input\n";
      cin >> status;
    }
    //teacher section
    if(status == 1){
      cout << "Do you want to change the test key? Y/N\n";
      cin >> keyChoice;
      if(keyChoice == 'Y' || keyChoice == 'y'){
        //loops through all questions so the user can input new answers
        for(int question = 1; question <= 20; question++){
          cout << "What is the new answer to question " << question << ":\t";
          cin >> newAnswer;
          while(newAnswer != 'a' && newAnswer != 'A' && newAnswer != 'b' && newAnswer != 'B' && newAnswer != 'c' && newAnswer != 'C' && newAnswer != 'd' && newAnswer != 'D'){
            cout << "Input valid answer\n";
            cin >> newAnswer;
          }
          answers[question-1] = putchar(toupper(newAnswer));
          cout << endl;
        }
        //output new key
        cout << "The new key is:\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
          cout << "Question " << i << ": " << answers[i+1] << endl;
        }
      }
      //student section
    }else{
      do{
        cout << CLEAR;
        //start test
        for(int question = 1; question <= 20; question++){
          cout << "What is the answer to question " << question << ":\t";
          cin >> questionAnswer;
          while(questionAnswer != 'a' && questionAnswer != 'A' && questionAnswer != 'b' && questionAnswer != 'B' && questionAnswer != 'c' && questionAnswer != 'C' && questionAnswer != 'd' && questionAnswer!= 'D'){
            cout << "Input valid answer to question " << question << endl;
            cin >> questionAnswer;
          }
          testAnswers += putchar(toupper(questionAnswer));
          cout << endl;
         }
        //grades test
        int rightAnswers = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
          if(testAnswers[i] == answers[i]){
            rightAnswers += 1;
          }else{
            cout << "You got question " << i + 1 << " wrong\n";
          }
        }
        //output the users score and if they passed or not
        cout << "You got " << rightAnswers << " questions right and " << (rightAnswers - 20) * -1 << " questions wrong\n";
        if(rightAnswers >= 15){
        cout << "You have passed the exam\n";
        }else{
        cout << "You have failed the exam\n";
        }
        cout << "Would you like to take the exam again? Y/N\n";
        cin >> choice;
      }while(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
    }
    cout << "Are you done with the driver exam? Y/N\n";
    cin >> endProgram;
  }while(endProgram == 'n' || endProgram == 'N');
  cout << CLEAR;
  cout << "Goodbye";
}
```

Comment: `putchar` doesn't do what you think it does. What is your understanding of what `putchar` does? `putchar` is not even a C++ function, it's an old, prehistoric C library function, why did you think you needed to use it?

Comment: "*whenever I use `putchar()` it outputs the capitalized user output even though there is no `cout` that does that*" - [`putchar()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/putchar) writes a character to the `stdout` stream - the same output stream that `std::cout` writes to - and then returns the character that it wrote. You should not be using `putchar()` in this code, just get rid of it.

Comment: `answers[question-1] = putchar(toupper(newAnswer));` should simply be `answers[question-1] = toupper(newAnswer);`. Please review what `putchar()` actually does.

Comment: I thought that I needed to use putchar with toupper because toupper returns a number and putchar would convert it back into a character.

Comment: @KenY-N same with `testAnswers += putchar(toupper(questionAnswer));` -> `testAnswers += toupper(questionAnswer);`

Comment: @LucasSintim "*I used `toupper()` to make sure the answer the user gave was always uppercase (to make comparing the user answers to the test key easier)*" - or, you could just use a case-insensitive comparison function, like `stricmp()` or equivalent.

Comment: @LucasSintim "*`toupper` returns a number and [I thought] `putchar` would convert it back into a character*" - newsflash, if you actually look at `putchar()` (or read its documentation), you will see that it also returns an integer number! You "convert [the number] back to a character" by simply assigning the number to a `char` variable.